# When section reach on top then fixed left div and scroll right div till the end of the section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to display the left column fixed when reaching the top and right div will scroll. Once end the section then left div will change it relative so that it will also scroll at the end of the section.

I tried below code but it's not working perfectly for me. it's also changing the width.

I tried  `if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 350) {` which is not perfectly. It's active when scroll reaches 350. I need when my section reach on top then fixed the left div and and scroll right div.

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    //After scrolling 100px from the top...
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 350) {
      $('.leftDiv').css('position', 'fixed');
      $('.leftDiv').css('top', '0px');
      //Otherwise remove inline styles and thereby revert to original stying
    } else {
      $('.leftDiv').css('position', 'static');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie risus.
      Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium, velit dui
      pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis turpis sed urna
      tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
      himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare nisl. Quisque mollis est
      nulla, eget aliquam nisi dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus enim non mollis. Aenean finibus
      urna ipsum, id aliquet odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui.
      Proin ligula erat, vestibulum malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie risus.
      Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium, velit dui
      pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis turpis sed urna
      tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
      himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare nisl. Quisque mollis est
      nulla, eget aliquam nisi dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus enim non mollis. Aenean finibus
      urna ipsum, id aliquet odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui.
      Proin ligula erat, vestibulum malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie risus.
      Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium, velit dui
      pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis turpis sed urna
      tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
      himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare nisl. Quisque mollis est
      nulla, eget aliquam nisi dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus enim non mollis. Aenean finibus
      urna ipsum, id aliquet odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui.
      Proin ligula erat, vestibulum malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="leftDiv">
          <h2>This div will fixed once touch the top bar and scroll right div</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <div class="rightDiv">
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie
            risus. Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium,
            velit dui pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis
            turpis sed urna tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
            nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare
            nisl. Quisque mollis est nulla, eget aliquam nisi dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus
            enim non mollis. Aenean finibus urna ipsum, id aliquet odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare
            magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui. Proin ligula erat, vestibulum malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non
            vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie
            risus. Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium,
            velit dui pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis
            turpis sed urna tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
            nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare
            nisl. Quisque mollis est nulla, eget aliquam nisi dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus
            enim non mollis. Aenean finibus urna ipsum, id aliquet odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare
            magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui. Proin ligula erat, vestibulum malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non
            vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
        </div>
      </div>




    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section>
  <div class="container">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie risus.
      Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium, velit dui
      pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis turpis sed urna
      tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
      himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare nisl. Quisque mollis est
      nulla, eget aliquam nisi dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus enim non mollis. Aenean finibus
      urna ipsum, id aliquet odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui.
      Proin ligula erat, vestibulum malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie risus.
      Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium, velit dui
      pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis turpis sed urna
      tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
      himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis
      et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl
      at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent
      taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat
      bibendum. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Interdum et
      malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare nisl. Quisque mollis est nulla, eget aliquam nisi
      dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus enim non mollis. Aenean finibus urna ipsum, id aliquet
      odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui. Proin ligula erat, vestibulum
      malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I need to know how you format my code?

Comment: [How to format posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I just used Tidy which is in the snippet.

Comment: I also separated out the JS logic in to it's own section so it's easier for others to read and edit.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Yes, I checked, Thanks for the editing my code. So do you have any idea where I am doing working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page load, find the elements position in the page, using [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), and it's width, using [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Also, you can pass multiple CSS properties at once, using [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), if you format them as an object (see below).

Now... You also have to care about the next row below... So a simple math will compare the scrollTop in order to "un-fix" the div as soon as the next row comes into view. That is the scrollTop + row height - the div's height.

```js
$(function() {

  // Get position and width
  var position = $(".leftDiv").offset().top;
  var width = $(".leftDiv").width();

  // Get the height and the row height
  var height = $(".leftDiv").height();
  var row_height = $(".leftDiv").parents(".row").height();

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    // Compare scrollTop with the div position
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= position && $(window).scrollTop() <= position + row_height - height) {
      $('.leftDiv').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0,
        width: width // Ensure to keep its width
      });

      //Otherwise remove inline styles and thereby revert to original stying
    } else {
      $('.leftDiv').css({
        position: 'static'
      });
    }
  });

  // Resize issue... Since the width has been set once
  $(window).on("resize", function() {

    // Remove the width and position properties to redefine all variables
    $(".leftDiv").css({
      position: 'static',
      width: "initial"
    });

    // Get position and width
    position = $(".leftDiv").offset().top;
    width = $(".leftDiv").width();

    // Get the height and the row height
    height = $(".leftDiv").height();
    row_height = $(".leftDiv").parents(".row").height();

    // Run the scroll adjusments...
    $(window).trigger("scroll");
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie risus.
      Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium, velit dui
      pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis turpis sed urna
      tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
      himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare nisl. Quisque mollis est
      nulla, eget aliquam nisi dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus enim non mollis. Aenean finibus
      urna ipsum, id aliquet odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui.
      Proin ligula erat, vestibulum malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie risus.
      Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium, velit dui
      pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis turpis sed urna
      tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
      himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare nisl. Quisque mollis est
      nulla, eget aliquam nisi dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus enim non mollis. Aenean finibus
      urna ipsum, id aliquet odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui.
      Proin ligula erat, vestibulum malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie risus.
      Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium, velit dui
      pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis turpis sed urna
      tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
      himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare nisl. Quisque mollis est
      nulla, eget aliquam nisi dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus enim non mollis. Aenean finibus
      urna ipsum, id aliquet odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui.
      Proin ligula erat, vestibulum malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="leftDiv">
          <h2>This div will fixed once touch the top bar and scroll right div</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <div class="rightDiv">
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</h2>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie
            risus. Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium,
            velit dui pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis
            turpis sed urna tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
            nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare
            nisl. Quisque mollis est nulla, eget aliquam nisi dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus
            enim non mollis. Aenean finibus urna ipsum, id aliquet odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare
            magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui. Proin ligula erat, vestibulum malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non
            vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie
            risus. Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium,
            velit dui pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis
            turpis sed urna tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
            nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare
            nisl. Quisque mollis est nulla, eget aliquam nisi dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus
            enim non mollis. Aenean finibus urna ipsum, id aliquet odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare
            magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui. Proin ligula erat, vestibulum malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non
            vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
        </div>
      </div>




    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section>
  <div class="container">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie risus.
      Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium, velit dui
      pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis turpis sed urna
      tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
      himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare nisl. Quisque mollis est
      nulla, eget aliquam nisi dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus enim non mollis. Aenean finibus
      urna ipsum, id aliquet odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui.
      Proin ligula erat, vestibulum malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam congue pretium quam id aliquet. Maecenas feugiat augue sed suscipit pulvinar. Mauris at pharetra libero, vel efficitur mi. Proin vel neque laoreet, dictum augue faucibus, molestie risus.
      Suspendisse vitae elit enim. Curabitur lobortis hendrerit eros, ac commodo sapien efficitur et. Praesent quis vehicula nisi. Aenean gravida lacus dolor, at vehicula eros accumsan facilisis. Proin posuere, magna sit amet maximus pretium, velit dui
      pretium nisi, ut fringilla mauris diam ut nulla. Nullam rhoncus nunc id mauris vulputate, a tincidunt ligula posuere. Nunc sed tortor eget augue sollicitudin mattis. Pellentesque interdum fringilla risus in iaculis. Proin facilisis turpis sed urna
      tempor, ac hendrerit sem tristique. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos
      himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis
      et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl
      at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent
      taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat
      bibendum. Donec rutrum gravida ultricies. Morbi eleifend a turpis et convallis. Morbi sed felis a tortor maximus lobortis non sit amet ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Interdum et
      malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse a nisl at nulla fringilla egestas. Phasellus ac libero nisl. Nullam quis lacus quis arcu consequat bibendum. Phasellus faucibus ornare nisl. Quisque mollis est nulla, eget aliquam nisi
      dignissim quis. Donec semper euismod elit sed tristique. Etiam ut purus pulvinar, dictum eros ultricies, elementum libero. Nulla vulputate mauris at venenatis gravida. Praesent efficitur maximus enim non mollis. Aenean finibus urna ipsum, id aliquet
      odio venenatis vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a euismod lectus, viverra fermentum leo. Maecenas vulputate, ante id tempus pharetra, eros ligula ornare magna, eu egestas arcu sapien vel dui. Proin ligula erat, vestibulum
      malesuada egestas molestie, accumsan porta leo. Duis lacinia, sem in dapibus bibendum, libero erat venenatis ligula, nec vestibulum nisi est eu leo. Nulla sodales ex non vestibulum pellentesque. </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Interesting "Bonus question"**

> Can I use some animation at the end when the section ends because left content directly goes off?

Since that is a "bonus question"... and a bit more complex, I will post it only on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KEyVwV).

Quick explanations: you have to make sure the animation triggers only once. So I used a class, that will be removed instantly... while the `position` will be changed to `static` only at the animation end.

Additionally, the animation only is interesting to have if the scrolling is at the bottom of the row... It looks strange at top.

Comment: Yes, I checked, It's working almost, but at the end once end the section then can we scroll the left div? because it's overlaying my content at the end.

Comment: Give me some time to understand your answer.

Comment: I edited again, because there was an eventual issue about page resizing... Like if this snippet was ran in "full page" mode. I fixed it. ;)

Comment: Yes, That' correct. Can I use some animation at the end when the section ends because left content directly goes off? Or else instead of static I can scroll the left div. What say? So it will look like left div also scroll at the end.

Comment: mmm... Let me think. Triggering animations on scroll is a bit tricky.

Comment: Not that much important but if you got the answer then Please update. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate. Upvote from my side.

Comment: See edit and CodePen for the animation. ;) Have a nice day!

Comment: Oh!, That's great. Thanks again.

Comment: I was talking about this scroll. Please check second section https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/analytics/.      after reaching at the end of the section that image also scrolls.

Comment: The example you posted is achieved with `position:sticky`... See [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)... But it's not yet completely browser friendly: [canIuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)

Comment: Yes, google using position:sticky for that scenario.